# How to add an「i」button like the Stocks application in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I want to add an「i」button on the top right in the navigationbar, just like the one in the Stocks application. Does iPhone SDK has this built-in button? I looked up the document but couldn't find any. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, this is a standard UIButton with a type of info light. You can set it up in IB. However, you can't add it to your Navigation Bar, since nav bars can only have bordered buttons. The simple solution is to create it manually and it via code using [UIBarButtonItem initWithCustomView:...]